# "Unexpected token stripe" when trying to deploy Firebase Functions

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to incorporate Stripe into an iOS app using Firebase Functions. I'm following the Stripe documentation for "Accepting a payment" in Swift with Node backend. I first did `npm install --save stripe`. That finished with no errors. Then I did `npm install`. My *index.js* looks like this so far:

```
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_...');

const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: 1099,
  currency: 'usd',
});
const clientSecret = paymentIntent.client_secret
```

When running `firebase deploy` I get: `11:29  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token stripe`. Line 11 char 29 in my file is the `stripe.paymentIntents`...

This is my first time using Firebase Functions or Stripe, so I'm at a loss here. I appreciate any help.

EDIT:

Here's the contents of my `package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "stripe": "^8.55.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: could you share a bigger part of you `index.js` this because with the portion of code you shared and the `package.json` it compiles

Comment: @JoséSoní Sure, just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because on the cloud environment the stripe library is not installed before you require it.

`npm install` does install the dependencies but in your local environment, to install them on the Cloud Functions envirornment you need to edit the `package.json` file from the Cloud Function.

This to [add the dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs) that it will be required by the function.

This is done by adding the dependency section to the `package.json` file

It will lok something like:

```
{
  "name": "sample-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "escape-html": "^1.0.3",
    "stripe": "^8.24.0"
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

With this code it works on Cloud functions:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('<My Secret Key>');

exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let paymentIntent = null;

  paymentIntent = stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: 2000,
  currency: 'usd',
  description: 'My first payment',
});
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

Apparently the issue was the await because HTTP Cloud Functions work on a Synchronous way

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I checked my `package.json` file and it already has stripe as a dependency.

Comment: could you share the `package.json` content?

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is old but I ran into this exact issue and couldn't find an answer.

I had my backend functions folder nested within my overall app and I had let firebase generate some files for me, including a lint configuration. So, I ended up with two lint config files in my project total. The firebase generated one tried to enforce double quotes and the one I created tried to enforce single quotes. I ended up just deleting the generated lint config and it works fine now.